# Spring Boot PostMapping Always Receives Null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a RESTful API in Java using Spring Boot.

What I want to do is to develop an endpoint which should receive a JSON value and finally return another JSON value. What I have tried so far is as below.

**BasicEntity:**

```
package com.mycompany.layer.entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BasicEntity {
    private Integer Id;
    private String Title;
    private String Field;
    private String ItemId;
    private String Question;
}
```

**MainEntity:**

```
package com.mycompany.layer.entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MainEntity {
    private BasicEntity[] MainData;
}
```

**MainController:**

```
package com.mycompany.layer.controller;

import com.mycompany.layer.entities.MainEntity;

import org.some.model.Q;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/main")
public class MainController {
    @PostMapping(path = "/transform",
                 consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                 produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Q> Transform(@RequestBody MainEntity mainEntity) {
        Q q = new Q();

        System.out.print(mainEntity); // mainEntity is null

        return new ResponseEntity<>(q, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I am using Postman to send the following JSON value, but always mainEntity is null in the server side when I send the request to the endpoint:

```
{
    "MainData": [
        {
            "Field": "E||D",
            "Id": 2,
            "Question": "Q1||Q2",
            "Title": "SomeTitle",
            "ItemId": "9||10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: When using lombok try following variable naming convention, like `Id` should be `id`, `Title` should be `title` and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fields start with UpperCase, it is not good practice for java.

Since your setter method is named **setMainData(…)** Jackson assumes the variable is named **mainData** because of the Java naming conventions (variables should start with lower case letters).

You can add `@JsonProperty` like below to your object for mapping.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MainEntity {
    @JsonProperty("MainData")
    private BasicEntity[] MainData;
}
```

Comment: Just to add, the same goes for the BasicEntity - it will map to null if sent with UpperCase. Also there are more bad practices than uppercasing properties. Consider using List or Set instead of an Array. Use int instead of Integer and perhaps use Value instead of Data to make your value objects immutable.